# How to combine outputs from two procedures into one output from different procedure?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two procedures named validateChar and endingSpaces. My output for both these procedures are a value displayed in a MsgBox.

I want to combine the value of the 2 message boxes into 1 value to be displayed in a MsgBox. I created a new procedure tempValidate to handle all my procedures with MsgBox.

Is there a way that I can combine not just 2 MsgBox but multiple message boxes?

In below code, msg1 and msgSpaces are variables in the 2 procedures (validateChar and endingSpaces).

```
Public Sub tempValidate()

    validateChar
    endingSpaces

    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name, msg1, msgSpaces, Title:="Call-outs"

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "combine message boxes". You can of course, combine strings and have several subs/functions first run, gathering the necessary data into a single string, displaying it when finished. Also: a message box really isn't an "output" -- it is a *side effect* of running your subs. If you want to combine actual output, refactor your code so that it either has a global string variable which can keep track of the growing message (not the best idea) or has some output-producing *functions* rather than subs (a much better idea) which later subs/functions can use.

Comment: @John Coleman, On my 2 procedures that I mentioned the Output are message boxes. Now I want to put it into 1 message under new procedure.

How can I create a global variables and how can I use it ?

Comment: But a message box isn't output at all since it is not a returned value. Feedback to the user isn't the same thing as output of some code. Subs don't have output.

Comment: Actually that script is only to validate values on Cells. Just for checking and I want the ouput to be  a msgbox to list or display all the incorrect values.

Comment: I understand that you want a message box, but the point of my comment is that a the message in a message box is something meant for a human user to see, not something meant for VBA to use.

Comment: @John Coleman, Thanks .. I will try this 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vars you declare and assign values to in a sub procedure cannot be referenced by another sub procedure.

Either you need public vars that can be shared across multiple sub procedures or you need to pass along a var byRef from a main sub to companion subs.

In the following, a single msg string-type var is declared in the primary tempValidate sub procedure and given an initial value of the active worksheet's name. The var is passed to both validateChar and endingSpaces and each companion sub appends the same string with additional information. The end result is displayed in a msgbox from tempValidate before exiting the procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tempValidate()

    Dim msg As String

    msg = ActiveSheet.Name & vbLf

    validateChar msg
    endingSpaces msg

    MsgBox msg, Title:="Call-outs"

End Sub

Sub validateChar(ByRef msg1 As String)

    'don't try to redeclare msg1 here
    'if you have Dim msg1 as string then get rid of it

    msg1 = msg1 & "The stuff from validateChar." & vbLf

End Sub

Sub endingSpaces(ByRef msgSpaces As String)

    'don't try to redeclare msgSpaces here
    'if you have Dim msgSpaces as string then get rid of it

    msgSpaces = msgSpaces & "The stuff from endingSpaces." & vbLf

End Sub
```

[image]

Another option would be to make those companion subs functions that returned strings. Perhaps another contributor can cover that scenario.

Comment: Thanks again .. That is my expected output but is there a way that I can declare a variable for '"The stuff from endingSpaces."' and The stuff from validateChar

Comment: The var is being passed to each of the validateChar and endingSpaces subs from tempValidate where it is initially declared.

Comment: This is a good solution (and seems somewhat C-like). I thought `ByRef` was the default. Is it needed in this case?

Comment: @JohnColeman, Yes it is the default but since this is a first-time learning experience for the op, I wanted to err on the verbose side.

Comment: @Jeeped, I got an error.  "Ambiguous name detected: validateChar."

Comment: Yes, I used the same procedure names that you provided in the sample at the top of this page. This is a demonstration; perhaps it should go into a new workbook so you can experiment until you are comfortable with the method.

Comment: It works, I will try to add some more procedures. thanks @Jeeped

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could use a public variable (here called message) to do what you want. In general, public variables are frowned upon, but they have some uses. In this case it would allow the rest of your code to be left almost alone (simply replace the any line `Msgbox s` by `LogMessage s`):

```
Public message As String

Sub LogMessage(s As String)
    message = message & IIf(Len(message) > 0, vbCrLf, "") & s
End Sub

Sub test1()
    LogMessage "Hello"
End Sub

Sub test2()
    LogMessage "World"
End Sub

Sub main()
    message = ""
    test1
    test2
    MsgBox message 'prints "Hello World" on two lines
End Sub
```

You could of course replace `vbCrLf` by some other delimiter such as `", "`.